# what is the real type of auto in c++ struct binding

Tags: c++, c++17

> example 1:

```
    int a1 = 0;
    double b1 = 1.0;
    char c1 = 'c';
    string d1 ="ddd";
    tuple tu = {a1, b1, c1, d1};  //using list initlization
    auto [a2, b2, c2, d2] = tu;   //using struct binding
```

what is the real type of auto in this code? how can I see that?

Is it a tuple? I make the code below to verify this and I can use tuple to replace it and work the same

> example 2:

```
    int a1 = 0;
    double b1 = 1.0;
    char c1 = 'c';
    string d1 ="ddd";
    tuple tu = {a1, b1, c1, d1};  
    tuple [a2, b2, c2, d2] = tu;
```

however, when I use a array to assign, compilation errors come

> example 3:

```
    int array[]={1,2,3,4};                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    tuple [a3, b3, c3, d3] = array;  

main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:34:11: error: 4 names provided for structured binding
   34 |     tuple [a3, b3, c3, d3] = array;
      |           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:34:11: note: while ‘std::tuple<int*>’ decomposes into 1 element
```

then I think auto should decided by the assign expression I want to use int[] to replace tuple, but there are still wrong

> example 4:

```
     int array[]={1,2,3,4};                                                                                                                                                                                                            
     int[] [a3, b3, c3, d3] = array;

main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:34:8: error: structured binding declaration cannot have type ‘int’
   34 |     int[] [a3, b3, c3, d3] = array;
      |        ^~
main.cpp:34:8: note: type must be cv-qualified ‘auto’ or reference to cv-qualified ‘auto’
main.cpp:34:8: error: empty structured binding declaration
main.cpp:34:11: error: expected initializer before ‘[’ token
   34 |     int[] [a3, b3, c3, d3] = array;
      |
```

how to understand type of auto, do we can only use 'auto' in struct binding? if yes, how to understand example 1?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding

Comment: The code in question is invalid.

Comment: thanks for @cpplearner reminding, I have already rectified description of problem

Comment: `auto` doesn't stand for any particular type in these examples. Think of it as just part of the syntax. Kind of like square brackets that start a lambda expression don't mean you are dealing with an array. Or like `static` keyword means different things in different contexts.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: That’s true, although there is an invisible `auto&&` variable declared into which the individual bindings refer.